# CAFF creation on Windows (or Linux)

Tags: iphone, windows, afconvert

On OS X I use this command to convert a sound file to CAFF for iPhone.

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 file.wav file.caf
```

I need to do the same on a Windows box.

Any clues?

I'd even settle for a Linux version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search revealed the following:

> Yeah but you dont need pro. You can
>   use iTunes though you have to go under
>   the preferences and change it from
>   converting a sound file to wav to aiff
>   but you still have to rename the .aiff
>   to .caf

[Sauce Here](http://modmyi.com/forums/skinning-themes-discussion/1769-how-do-i-create-caf-file.html).